# How to add a panel with definition about plots, accompanied by dot and dot-dash lines?

Tags: plotting, graphics, export

```
u = 2/(1 + Z1) Sech[T/Z1 + 1/(9 Z1) Log[1 + Z1]]^2;
w = 2/(1 + Z2) Sech[T/Z2 + 1/(9 Z2) Log[1 + Z2]]^2;
Z1 = 5;
Z2 = 10;


Plot[{u, w}, {T, -15, 15}, PlotRange -> {0, 0.45}, Frame -> True, 
 Axes -> {False, False}, 
 Epilog -> {Inset[
    Graphics[{DotDashed, Line[{{0, 0}, {0.19, 0}}]}], {10, 0.41}], 
   Inset["z=0.1", {13, 0.41}], 
   Inset[Graphics[{Dashed, Line[{{0, 0}, {0.19, 0}}]}], {10, 0.38}], 
   Inset["z=0.2", {13, 0.38}]}, PlotStyle -> {DotDashed, Dashed}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

When I want is to change the format of the plot into EPS, though some parts of the plot programed by using `Epilog` and `Inset` ( I mean `"_._. Z=0.1"` and `"_ _ _Z=0.2"`) change their forms and make the plot unreadable! How can I revise my program? I think I should use `Panel` but I dont know how!

Comment: `ImportString[ExportString[p, "EPS"], "EPS"]` (where `p` is the plot) works [mostly fine](http://i.stack.imgur.com/yD227.png) for me on win7 mma8. Can you specify preciser what the problem is?

Comment: [The result I get](http://ge.tt/2Rjd0kI/v/0?c) using `Export["g.eps", g]` looks fine.  How do you export and what do you get as output?  What version of Mathematica do you have?

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments, the results from eps export look fine. However, you can use an alternative version of your `Epilog` with a single `Inset` working with scaled coordinates as follows:

```
Epilog -> 
 Inset[
   Grid[{{Graphics[{DotDashed, Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}]}, 
          AspectRatio -> .1, ImageSize -> 30], Style["z=0.1", 12]}, 
         {Graphics[{Dashed, Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}]}, 
           AspectRatio -> .1, ImageSize -> 30], Style["z=0.2", 12]}}], 
   Offset[{-10, -10}, Scaled[{1, 1}]], {Right, Top}]
```

(Check for details [Inset > Applications > first example](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Inset.html) in the docs on the content and placement of insets.)

Or, you can wrap the `Grid` with `Panel`:

```
Epilog ->  Inset[Panel@Grid[...]]
```

If you replace the `Epilog->...` part of your code with these versions, you get

[image]